# First / Last child for margin not working in the Next.js, Tailwindcss environment

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

The same thing happened with this github issue.

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1930

First / Last child for margin not working in the Next.js, Tailwindcss environment.

```
# not working
mt-4 first:mt-0
```

I would like to know the solution.
thanks.

Comment: Did you enable the `first-child` variant for `margin` like it's mentioned in the GitHub issue you linked?

Comment: I added it, but I couldn't.

I decided that the current version of Next.js and Tailwindcss do not mix well, so I gave up.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the space-y utitlity class